# Teamviewer remote install on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, remote, teamviewer

Ok so it took some time, but was able to install and use teamviewer on a remote 14.04, at last.

This [post](http://www.tonisoto.com/2013/07/launching-teamviewer-remotely-throught-ssh/) was of some help.

Basically (that part is actually an answer by itself!)

- install the 32 bits package version (14.04 is multiarch)
- start the daemon, set a password (see link above)
- get the ID from `/opt/teamviewer/config/global.com`
- start the client as regular user

and after a few core dumps (harmless seemingly) of the daemon (Linux binary) while setting password, ranting about TV and their lack of option consistency (and no error when entering a wrong option), ... having to start the client (using *wine* since no bin client exist seemingly) for some reasons (while being remote).. (All of that question the quality of TV developments, but that's not the point...)

And that's it - or... is it?

Well, had to figure out that the error "Authentication rejected" kept coming on to the (actual) client (a Mac) - the logs being useless - because the client (server side!) was expecting a License Agreement OK click... (used *xdotool*, *gnome-screenshot*, *rsync* to visualize a screenshot of the Ubuntu screen!)

Finally using *xdotool* could manage to remote-click the OK (license agreement) + the next warning... and hurra! Worked!

For the sake of completeness, efficiency and serenity... when a local install was not possible/made prior to remote access

- is there a way to install teamviewer without all these pirouettes - i.e. at least without having to locally agree the License Agreement (which defeats the purpose of a remote install - *xdotool* is a nice tool but that's really awkward!) ?

Comment: This is a very pertinent question ! Still unresolved

Answer (score 1):

In TeamViewer 10 there is a option `licence`, with which you can accept the EULA.

```
$teamviewer license accept
```

You may need to restart teamviewer daemon with `$teamviewer daemon restart`.

Comment: The question is: `is there a way to install teamviewer without all these pirouettes - i.e. at least without having to locally agree the License Agreement (which defeats the purpose of a remote install - xdotool is a nice tool but that's really awkward!) ?`